# Silverlight: Is HtmlPage.Window.Invoke() synchronous?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, asynchronous, invoke

Do calls made from Silverlight to Javascript through HtmlPage.Window.Invoke() return immediately or are they synchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke is synchronous from the point of view of your Silverlight code - control will not return to the Silverlight code until the JavaScript code returns. It's easy to see this must be the case because `Invoke` returns a value which you can use immediately.

You can even call back *into* Silverlight from JavaScript via a `ScriptableMember` in a nested fashion during the call (though I wouldn't recommend ping-ponging back and forth like that!).

This synchronous calling can be problematic, not just for responsiveness - some [nasty reentrancy issues](http://nerddawg.blogspot.com/2010/04/of-crashing-and-sometimes-burning.html) can arise. I'd recommend either keeping JavaScript code you call from Silverlight as small as possible, or failing that set a timer to run some code, so that control will return immediately to Silverlight, and the code will execute from the JavaScript event loop instead (giving you effectively an asynchronous call).